# R dplyr mutate conditional when_case fails to update dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am using R `dplyr::mutate` to conditionally change a data frame variable value. The df_forecast is derived from a CSV file input using `stringsAsFactors=F`.

The variable attribute `Acres` is a string, later to be cast to a factor, which contains '10-Jan' (1/10/2019). I am attempting to mutate the value of Acres '10-Jan' to '1 to 10', but the mutate is not making any changes inside the data frame.

This same failure update issue is on the second code example for 'YearBuilt' below: trying to clean / change '15' to '2015'.

I am using R Studio (3.5).

dplyr effort explored:

I have tried equal assignment

> 'mutate(df_forecast$Acres = case_when...' which resulted in this error msg: 'Error: unexpected '=' in:
>   "df_forecast %>% 
>     mutate(df_forecast$Acres ="'

I tried '==' to 'mutate(df_forecast$Acres == case_when...' which resulted with 'data.frame': 22745 obs. of  19 variables

```
df_forecast <- data.frame(forecast)
df_forecast %>% 
  mutate(df_forecast$Acres == case_when(df_forecast$Acres == "10-Jan" ~ "1 to 10")) %>% 
##
str(df_forecast)

df_forecast %>% 
  mutate(df_forecast$YearBuilt == case_when(df_forecast$YearBuilt == "15" ~ "2015")) %>% 
##
str(df_forecast)
```

Comment: Only use single `=` before `case_when` as it is an assignment operator `mutate(df_forecast$Acres = case_when......`. Also you would also need a `TRUE` condition.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share some of your data, for example the output of `dput(head(<YourData>))`.

Comment: ok: c("10-Jan", "10-Jan", "10-Jan", "10-Jan", "10-Jan", "10-Jan")

Comment: the original CVS file has this column data as: "1/10/2019"

Comment: do you get any error messages? Because the code works for me if `Acres` is `character`. Is you `Acres`maybe `factor`?

Comment: I read the CSV as stringsAsFactors=F. so Acres is character

Comment: when I ran the code, I got an echo of the result for the rows that matched the conditional "10-Jan", but when I inspect the str(df) I see that Acres still has the original "10-Jan"

Comment: check the update to my answer. Do you assign your changes to your `df_forecast`-data.frame? In your comment to Cettt it didn't look like it

Comment: would that assignment be 'mutate(Acres = case_when...' ?

Comment: mutate(Acres = case_when... conditional Acres == "10-Jan" ~ "1 to 10"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to write `df_forecast$Acres` just `Acres` and specifiy what has to happen when none of the conditions apply.

```
data <- data.frame(Acres = c("10-Jan", "10-Jan", "anytime", "10-Jan", "10-Jan", "anytime"),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 

> data
    Acres
1  10-Jan
2  10-Jan
3 anytime
4  10-Jan
5  10-Jan
6 anytim


data %>% 
  mutate(Acres = case_when(Acres == "10-Jan" ~ "1 to 10",
                           TRUE ~ Acres)) -> data

> data
    Acres
1 1 to 10
2 1 to 10
3 anytime
4 1 to 10
5 1 to 10
6 anytime
```

I just assigned the content of `Acres` back to `Acres` when `Acres != "10-Jan"`, but it can be anything.

UPDATE: To make the changes permanent you also have to assign the result to your data.frame.

Comment: df_forecast %>% 
  mutate(Acres = case_when(Acres == "10-Jan" ~ "1 to 10", 
                           TRUE ~ Acres)) > df_forecast

Comment: df_forecast %>% 
  mutate(Acres = case_when(Acres == "10-Jan" ~ "1 to 10", 
                           TRUE ~ Acres)) > df_forecast$Acres

Comment: I see where you are making the assignment to > data in your code. I tried the same assignment with no noticeable change in the dataframe